# Undefined Method on has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through

I have three models:

```
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :tags, :through => :tasks
end

Class Tasks < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

Class Tags < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
  has_many :projects, :through => :tasks
```

When I open up console, I can get my Project and Task information as expected:

```
Tag.find(1).projects
Tag.find(1).tasks
```

If I want, I can get all the tasks for each project regardless of the tag:

```
Project.find(1).tasks
```

For whatever reason, I can't access tasks if I get projects by tag...
    something = Tag.find(1).projects
    something.tasks

...I get the error:

```
undefined method `tasks' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007feae4af0e70>
```

I've looked for a couple hours and can't find anything that corrects this problem.  Based on everything I've found, it should be working... but it's not.

I'm using Rails 3.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't `Tag.find(1).tasks` give you the same result?

Anyway, the problem you're facing is that you're trying to retrieve an association from a `Relation` object instead of an instance of your model. `Relations` can be used to chain query conditions, but you can't directly reference associations from them. So, to get your example working, you'd need to do

```
p = Tag.find(1).projects.includes(:tasks)
```

Then reference tasks like this: `p[0].tasks`.

However I'd just make sure that `Tag.find(1).tasks` will generate the same SQL and ultimately return the same collection of `tasks`.

Comment: To your question, actually it wouldn't.  It does give me all the tagged tasks regardless of project.  I was looking for the tasks as a subset of each project, hence the `Tag.find(1).projects.tasks` attempt.

I did just get it working but I think you explained it. My original approach was trying to get results for several different projects at the same time.  `p[0].tasks` works to get me the result I'm looking for.  

Thanks for the help!